# Check how much of an image is transparent with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In plain javascript I need to check if the majority of an image is transparent.

e.g if more than 50% of the image is less than 10% visible then consider it transparent.

I need a way to filter out all these images as they're usually completely blank or just have a little logo on them.

Comment: That's good to know what you want/need but what have you tried so far and which part are you having issues with? What research have you done... No source code = nothing to debug/fix and this isn't a free writing service.

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287823/check-image-transparency first result after searching "check image transparency javascripit"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check image transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287823/check-image-transparency)

Comment: It is a bit different than the mentioned as possible duplicate, as there will be in this case a threshold to consider an image transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function opacityRatio(image) {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    const data = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
    let opacity = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        opacity += data[i + 3];
    }
    return (opacity / 255) / (data.length / 4);
}
```

This function will return a number from 0 to 1, being 0 a fully transparent image, 1 a fully opaque one. Note that it is using getImageData, and to work, the image needs to be hosted in the same origin/domain or to have cross-origin permissions.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

first make a state

```
  const [isTransparent, setIsTransparent] = useState(false);
```

than use this function

```
  const checkImageTransparency = (event) => {
const img = event.target;
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);

// Iterate through image data and check if any pixel has an alpha value less than 255
let isTransparent = false;
for (let i = 3; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
  if (imageData.data[i] !== 255) {
    isTransparent = true;
    break;
  }
}

setIsTransparent(isTransparent);
```

};

after that call it in onLoad method of iamge

```
    onLoad={(event) => {
    checkImageTransparency(event);
    if (onLoad) {
      onLoad(event);
    }
  }}
```

Now by using state you can set color like this

```
    backgroundColor: isTransparent ? "#eae9e7ff  " : "transparent",
```